# Pass string into map_dfr to filter using tidyfst

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, fst

I'm reading data stored in several fst-files using `tidyfst` and `purrr::map_dfr`. The following example works as expected.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fst)
library(tidyfst)

# get all fst files in current directory
files_fst <- file.path(list.files(pattern = ".fst"))

df <- map_dfr(files_fst,
              ~ parse_fst(.) %>% 
                filter_fst(country == "France")) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

However, using a variable containing the string for which I want to filter does not work:

```
country_in <- "France"

df <- map_dfr(files_fst,
              ~ parse_fst(.) %>% 
                filter_fst(country == country_in)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Any ideas what's the problem here?

Comment: Not able to reproduce your case with an example like `fst::write_fst(iris,"iris_test.fst");
  v1 <- "setosa";
  list(parse_fst("iris_test.fst"), parse_fst("iris_test.fst")) %>% map(~ .x %>% filter_fst(Species == v1))`

Comment: I assume that you don't have a column named `country_in`

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I made some adjustments, now it seems to work!